# Save click event in local storage

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to save this event in local storage without using libraries?

I saw some solutions here on stackoverflow and on the internet with jQuery but it’s not exactly what I need and I was not able to convert...

```js
const click = document.querySelector(".click")
const content = document.querySelector(".content")

click.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(content.classList.contains("active")){
    content.classList.remove("active")
  }
  else{
    content.classList.add("active")
  }
})
```

```css
.content{
  display:none;
}

.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="click">
  Click me
</div>
<div class="content">
  Hey!
</div>
```

Comment: save what exactly? That it is active? Set a variable.

Comment: "Vanilla JavaScript" isn't a thing. It's just called "JavaScript" or "JavaScript without libraries" or, if you must, "Core JavaScript". If you're wondering what JavaScript can do, the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a great place to search.

Comment: Please ask your question clearly.

Comment: vanilla javascript is just fine.  Now chocolate javascript is another story

Comment: look into  JSON.stringify(object) andJSON.parse(str);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem("active") && localStorage.getItem("active") === "yes")
    content.classList.add("active");
};
```

Here's the full snippet (snippet won't work because `localStorage` is not allowed in Stack Overflow):

```js
const click = document.querySelector(".click");
const content = document.querySelector(".content");

click.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (content.classList.contains("active")) {
    content.classList.remove("active");
    if (localStorage)
      localStorage.setItem("active", "no");
  } else {
    content.classList.add("active");
    if (localStorage)
      localStorage.setItem("active", "yes");
  }
});

window.onload = function () {
  if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem("active") && localStorage.getItem("active") === "yes")
    content.classList.add("active");
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.content {
  border: 2px dashed #e0e0e0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.content.active {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Hello!</div>
<button class="click">Click Me!</button>
```

If the sandbox snippet doesn't work, you can see the demo here: [**JSBin**](https://output.jsbin.com/weduqozulo)